# Uploading image from canvas to S3 in Meteor

Tags: canvas, file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3

I have no experiene with file uploads in any programming language, so this is a bit of hassle for me.

I have a canvas that needs to be saved in a bucket in Amazon S3 (or any other good service if it's simpler). I know about `toDataURL()` and that it can be useful in this case, but from there the step is still a big one to actually uploading it.

I've looked at a few packages, [Slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/) included, but the docs don't go through my use-case and they are very complex and, for me, largely incomprehensible.

Complicating the matter further is that I later want to add PDF file uploads, and that it would make sense to use the same package/service for that simply because it would save me a lot of time, but I don't know if such a versatile solution exists.

I'm a bit lost and perhaps looking for a more general guidance than is accepted here, but a good nudge in the right direction would also be acceptable.

It should also be noted that whenever I try to use `toDataURL()` I get this error:

> SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement':
>   Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot) is very much suited for it.

You need to extract a `Blob` from your canvas ([use this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)) and then pass it to slingshot:

```
function uploadImage(directive, canvas, type, callback) {
    var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload(directive);

    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
        blob.type = type;
        upload.send(blob, callback);
    }, type);

    return uploader;
}

uploadImage("myDirective", document.getElementById("mycanvas"), "image/png", function (error, downloadUrl) {
    console.log("file is now at %s", downloadUrl);
});
```

Now the server side could be (but it really depends on what you really want):

```
Slingshot.create("myDirective", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  allowedFileTypes: "image/png"

  acl: "public-read",

  authorize: function () {
    //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      var message = "Please login before posting files";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }

    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {
    //Store file into a directory by the user's username.
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return user.username + "/canvas.png";
  }
});
```

If you want to support pdf uploads, all you need to do is to add `application/pdf` to `allowedFileTypes` or create a separate directive that authorizes pdf uploads.

You can find some better docs on slingshot [at this unreleased branch](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/tree/subpackages).

Comment: Only says it saves it as "undefined" and it never shows up in S3.

Comment: should be fixed now, but it's up to you choose the file name.